# Generate a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the list

```
o = {xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax};
```

how can I generate the following list?

```
op = {{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}}, {{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, 
    ymax}}, {{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, 
    ymax}}};
```

Thank you very much.

(Just for the sake of completeness and since it was asked, I give more details.
I just wanted to generate a "Box". This was used to draw the bounding box of a rotated Ellipses, where the xmin, xmax etc are evaluated through the formulas in the article [here](http://quickcalcbasic.com/ellipse%20line%20intersection.pdf). The replies were very helpful. I think I can generate now the 3D analog:-)!)

Comment: How do you mean that?

Comment: I do not see the pattern.  Please describe it further.  If there is no pattern, then I suppose typing the list out is the best way to generate it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see the pattern. All min and all max are excluded, but otherwise it is a pairing the x's and the y's.

Comment: I just edited the post where I describe how it appeared the pattern. rcollyer  is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the bounding-box for an n-dimensional box like so:

```
bounds = {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}};
Select[Subsets[Tuples[bounds], {2}], HammingDistance @@ # == 1 &]
(*
  {{{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}}, {{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}},
   {{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}}}
*)
```

If you just want to traverse each point, and not necessarily generate every edge, you can order tuples according to [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) and then partition:

```
Partition[Tuples[bounds][[{1,2,4,3}]],2,1,1]
(*
  {{{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}}, {{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}},
   {{xmax, ymax}, {xmax, ymin}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmin, ymin}}}
*)
```

This can be drawn without lifting a pen, and while it's almost identical in 2D, it will have fewer elements in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 8):

One way:-

```
o = {xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax};

op = {{{#1, #3}, {#2, #3}}, {{#1, #3}, {#1, #4}},
   {{#1, #4}, {#2, #4}}, {{#2, #3}, {#2, #4}}} & @@ o
```

> {{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}}, {{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}},
>
> {{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}}}

Alternatively, (output in a slightly different order).

```
x = DeleteCases[Tuples[{ymin, ymax}, 2], {ymax, ymin}];

y = Transpose /@ Flatten[Map[Function[z, {z, #} & /@ x],
      DeleteCases[Tuples[{xmin, xmax}, 2], {xmax, xmin}]], 1] /.
   {a_, a_} -> Sequence[];

DeleteCases[y, {{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}}]
```

> {{{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}}, {{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}},
>
> {{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}}}

Comment: OK, I'll give it a +1, since it made me laugh. :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure this brute force method requires less time and effort than identifying the pattern.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I added a more thoughtful version :-)

Comment: Actually, now that I can see the pattern, I see that the `Slot` numbers reflect the pattern rather well.  Just couldn't see it before.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way, but it's in the wrong order:

```
Thread /@ (Partition[o, 2] /. {{___, #, ___} -> #} & /@ o)
(*
  {{{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}},
   {{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}}, {{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}}}
*)
```

If the order matters:

```
Thread /@ (Partition[o, 2] /. {{___, #, ___} -> #} & /@ 
   o[[{3, 1, 4, 2}]])
(*
  {{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}}, {{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}},
   {{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}}}
*)
```

---

P.S. A fairly easy way, given the OP has included the explicit output pattern is to use it for a replacement rule:

```
Replace[o, {xmin_, xmax_, ymin_, ymax_} :>
  {{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}}, {{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}},
   {{xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
parts = Partition[o, 2]

(*
    {{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax}}
*)

Thread[{#, parts[[2]]}] & /@ parts[[1]]

(*
    {{{xmin,ymin},{xmin,ymax}},{{xmax,ymin},{xmax,ymax}}}
*)

Thread[{parts[[1]], #}] & /@ parts[[2]]

(*
    {{{xmin,ymin},{xmax,ymin}},{{xmin,ymax},{xmax,ymax}}}
*)
```

The above result has the `Transpose` relation, so, combine them

```
{Transpose[#], #} &@(Thread[{#, parts[[2]]}] & /@ parts[[1]])

(*
    {{{{xmin,ymin},{xmax,ymin}},{{xmin,ymax},{xmax,ymax}}},{{{xmin,ymin},{xmin,ymax}},{{xmax,y
min},{xmax,ymax}}}}
*)

{Transpose[#], #} &@(Through /@ Outer @@ parts)

(*
    {{{xmin[ymin],xmin[ymax]},{xmax[ymin],xmax[ymax]}},{{xmin[ymin],xmax[ymin]},{xmin[ymax],xm
ax[ymax]}}}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

> ox = Partition[o, 2];
>
> p = Table[{ox[[1, i]], ox[[2, j]]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]

`{{{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}}, {{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}}}`

Not sure if this is what you want.

(The original post do not have a logic pattern...)

Answer (score 2):

In n-dimensions it can be done this way

```
dim = 2
o = Flatten[ToExpression[Table["x" <> ToString[i] <> j, {i, dim}, {j, {"min", "max"}}]]]
(*{x1min, x1max, x2min, x2max}*)

Select[Subsets[Tuples[Partition[o, 2]], {2}], Count[#[[1]] - #[[2]], 0] == dim - 1 &]
(*{{{x1min, x2min}, {x1min, x2max}}, {{x1min, x2min}, {x1max, x2min}}, {{x1min, x2max}, {x1max, x2max}}, {{x1max, x2min}, {x1max, x2max}}}*)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{aa = Most[Subsets[Flatten[{o[[#]], Drop[o, 2]}], {2}]] & /@ Range@2}, 
{First@# & /@ aa, aa[[1]], Last@# & /@ aa, aa[[2]]}]
```